# Is there a quick way to download a file which I have just copied the link to?

Tags: clipboard

I can open a terminal and wget it, or paste it into a web browser, but is there a way to do this from within unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is there a way to do this from within unity?

**No**

But you can try [steadyflow [image: Install steadyflow]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steadyflow) download manger it will detect link from clipboard

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Great! Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 2):

Install gpaste

Then write a bash file getlink.sh (I put mine on the desktop)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd ~/Desktop
    gpaste get 0 | (read link; wget $link;)
```

allow it to be an executable.

Create a launcher on your desktop and edit it with gedit so that it looks something like this:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
    Exec=/home/presbitero/Desktop/getlink.sh
    Name[en_US]=getlink
    Name=getlink
    Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
    Terminal=true
```

If your link was the last thing you copied this should download the file and paste it on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think, **FlareGet** would be an ideal choice for you as

> FlareGet is a full featured, multi-threaded and multi-segment download manager and accelerator

[FlareGet](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/flareget)

But the free version in Ubuntu software center does not support "Browser integration", you need to pay $10 to get browser integration plugin. I guess without browser integration, download manager won't make sense.

So here is the workaround to get Browser integration for Firefox. I have tested it on Firefox 18 and it works like a charm.

> - Just go to Firefox > Tools > Add ons > Extensions.
> - Search for addon "**FlashGot**", install it and Restart the Firefox.
> - Go to Tools > Add ons > Extension > Preferences for FlashGot.
> - On **General** tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show in Context Menu"
> - On **FlashGot Media** tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show Toolbar button".
> - Now restart the Firefox. FlashGot will act as Firefox integration plugin for FlareGet.

Just right click any downloadable link and choose FlareGet.

> If you want you download video from YouTube just play the video, an icon will appear on right most side of the tile bar. Just click on that icon and FlareGet will capture and download the video.

I love Firefox so this is enough for me. Something similar can be worked out for Chrome.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, often the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions (I recommend that here, as the questions, and thus the way this solution will be used, are substantially different), or (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question. (You can flag posts once you gain [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts) on the site.)